# Nullspace of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I think I lack understanding in this area as I tend to get stumped on the idea of 'null space' when it comes to understanding proofs/answering questions.

Even though I have some understanding already, could someone explain:

- what exactly is meant by the null space of a matrix $A$? Is it the kernel of the linear map $T$ associated with $A$ or the dimension of the kernel of $T$?
- how does one find the null space of a matrix $A$ and a basis for it. Is the null space a vector space?
- any other details you think are good to bear in mind when thinking about null spaces

Comment: The null space of $A$ is a vector space.  If $A$ is $m \times n$, then the nullspace is a *subspace* of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: The *nullity* is the dimension of the null space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The null space is the kernel of the transformation.
2. One finds the null space by solving $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ for $\vec{x}$.  Typically, this is done through Gaussian elimination.  And yes, the null space is a vector space: note that if $\vec{x},\vec{y}$ are in the null space and $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}$, then
   $$
   A(\alpha\vec{x}+\beta\vec{y})=\alpha(A\vec{x})+\beta(A\vec{y})=\alpha\vec{0}+\beta\vec{0}=\vec{0},
   $$
   so that $\alpha\vec{x}+\beta\vec{y}$ is also in the null space.